# Ubuntu 23.04 fixing thick window title bar on gtk.css won't work

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, ubuntu-gnome, css

I used xorg than Wayland on Ubuntu 23.04

Does anyone know why editing the .config/gtk3.0/gtk.css does not work and will not affect nautilus, VSCode and other app title bar/headerbar thickness on 23.04? Ubuntu 23.04 application title bar was thick af. The only affected apps are gnome-terminal and gnome-tweaks which correctly shrink in size, other apps don't shrink.

This is my complete code for shrinking the title bar/headerbar thickness, this works on 22.04, but on 23.04 it only applies to some application. By the way I also added CSS code to customize the title bar menu button icons, but I will not include it on the code below.

```css
headerbar {
  padding: 0 6px;
  min-height: 46px;
}

headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.default-decoration {
    min-height: 0; 
    padding: 0px;
}

.default-decoration .titlebutton {
    min-height: 2px; 
    min-width: 3px;
}

window.ssd headerbar.titlebar {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    min-height: 0;
}

window.ssd headerbar.titlebar button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

This is the result on 23.04 after saving and reloading.

[image: Result after saving and reloading (alt+f2 & r)]

As you can see it does not affect nautilus, Chrome, and VSCode. I also tried changing shell themes & icons, but it still doesn't affect the thickness and icon of the title bar/headerbar of these apps.

While on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, the result will be this.

[image: Result on 22.04 LTS]

As you can see on 22.04 LTS the styling is applied correctly accross all apps.

Answer (score 0):

It does not anymore work for these applications that moved to GTK4. This hack only works for applications using the GTK3 toolkit.

Comment: One could overwrite libadwaita - which is responsible for this mess - by adding its theme name into profiles. Documented [here](https://www.xfce-look.org/p/1424967)